Highchart Gantt chart y axies table, need to make it scrollable
How to make highchart's gantt chart side table horizontally scrollable ? I don't want to move whole chart along with y axis. I just want to make table scrollable.


Could you please provide a minimal reproducible demo along with additional information on how the scroll should work and under which conditions? You can start by editing this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/bhwm71a3/
